# Reading specific line into an array - ruby

Tags: ruby

Have a txt file with the following:

> ```
> Anders Hansen;87442355;11;87
> Jens Hansen;22338843;23;11
> Nanna Kvist;25233255;24;84
> ```

I would like to search the file after a specific name taken from the user input. Then save that line into an array, splittet via ";". Can't get it to work though. This is my code:

```
user1 = []
puts "Start by entering the full name of user 1: "
input = gets.chomp
File.open("userregister.txt") do |f|
f.each_line { |line|
  if line =~ input then do |line|
    user1 << line.split(';').map
```

Comment: Try replacing `line =~ input` with `line.start_with?(input)`.

Comment: That seems to work, cheers!!

Comment: Consider using [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) when you want to read a file line-by-line: `IO.foreach("userregister.txt") do |line| ... end`. (This is often written `File.foreach...`, which works because `File` is a subclass of `IO`.) One reason `foreach` is convenient is that, when used without a block, it returns an enumerator which can be chained to other methods, such as those in the `Enumerable` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=~` in ruby tries to match a string with a regex (or vice versa). Here, you use it with two strings, which gives an error:

```
'foo' =~ 'bar' # => TypeError: type mismatch: String given
```

There are more appropriate String methods to use instead. In your case, `#start_with?` does the job. If you wanted to check if the latter is contained somewhere as a substring (but not necessary the beginning), you can use `#include?`.

---

In case you actually wanted to take a regex as a user input (generally a bad idea), you can convert it from string to regex:

```
line =~ /#{input}/
```

Comment: What if there is a "Anders Hansonson", followed by "Anders Hanson", and you want the latter? Maybe `/\A#{input}:/` and ditch the `start_with?` option.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file format, I would actually use Ruby CSV class. By specifying the `column separator` to `;`, you will get an array for each row.

```
require 'csv'

input = gets.chomp
CSV.foreach('userregister.txt', col_sep: ';') do |row|
  if row[0].downcase == input.downcase
    # Do stuffs with row[1..-1]
  end
end
```